# Can I block a thread with name or a field?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have many threads to start. Some of them have the same name. I want to block a thread if its name is the same with another thread which is running. But if there is not a running thread with the same name, it can run immediately.

For example, I have 3 threads: A1, A2, B, and a thread pool. A1's name is "A", A2's name is "A", B's name is "B". When I execute the threads, if the start sequence is A1, A2, B, I want A2 is running after A1 has finished. But B is not affected for it's name is not "A". So B will run immediately.

Is there a simple implement? or I have to use Map?

Comment: Thread _names_ are really poor things to try to match on, because they can be arbitrarily changed.

Comment: If you don't want A1 and A2 to run concurrently, then why are they separate threads? Why are they not two _tasks_ that are performed sequentially by a single thread, "A"?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). No thread safety issue can be solved by allowing only some threads. And semantic problems are even less likely solvable by dealing with thread names.

Comment: @Solomon Slow
: because the threads are created by user. I do not know when it will be created. The thread has a field(or name) to differentiate  itself from others. I just want to make the threads with same name execute in order.

Comment: The threads aren't created by your program's users. They are created by _your code_ in response to user inputs. And, you wrote the code that way because you happened to think that was the best way to solve some problem. But maybe there is a better way. That's what Holger meant by "xy problem." You seek a solution to problem X (how to force certain threads to run sequentially) because you think that will solve problem Y. But maybe, if you explained problem Y, somebody could show you a more direct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't promise to give you the best solution because you have not described the underlying problem that you are trying to solve. (I.e., you have not named the "Y" in "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).") But, maybe I can offer *some* help.

It sounds as if your program maybe has different users ("A", "B", etc.) and it sounds as if the program creates new *tasks* ("A1", "A2", etc.) in response to user input. You want the tasks associated with any particular user to be *executed* sequentially, but you want to allow tasks belonging to different users to be executed concurrently.

Right now, you create a new thread for every new task. That's almost never a good idea. A better idea is to have a collection of *worker threads* that loop forever, picking tasks from a blocking queue and executing them:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue;
    public Worker(BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    @override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Runnable task = taskQueue.take();
            task.run();
        }
    }
}
```

That's the heart of a simplistic *thread pool.* The Java standard library has a much more sophisticated thread pool implementation, [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), but it doesn't quite do what you want because it won't guarantee to run certain tasks sequentially.

A normal thread pool has just one task queue from which all of the worker threads `take()` tasks. But if you had a thread pool in which each worker had its own queue, and if your thread pool had a `Map<Category,BlockingQueue<task>>` then it could assign all of the tasks belonging to the same category (e.g., to the same user) to the same worker thread, and that thread would perform the tasks one-by-one. Meanwhile, tasks belonging to other users could be assigned to different workers, and they could be executed concurrently with the first user's tasks.

---

I don't know of any ready-made implementation of this idea. It's something you'd have to code for yourself. Also, I don't have space here to talk about details such as, how to choose the number of workers, how to map users to workers, how to provide a shutdown mechanism (if needed) etc.

You could get arbitrarily sophisticated. Especially with the user->worker mapping: If Users A and B both map to the same worker, and if that worker has a backlog of requests from A when a new request from B comes in while some other worker is idle, then a sophisticated implementation might change the mapping for user B.

Comment: I use a Map<String, ExecutorService> to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

One thread can't safely block another (non-cooperating) thread.

There is ... `Thread.suspend()` ... but the javadoc says this:

> **Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.**
>
> This method has been deprecated, as it is inherently deadlock-prone. If the target thread holds a lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource when it is suspended, no thread can access this resource until the target thread is resumed. If the thread that would resume the target thread attempts to lock this monitor prior to calling resume, deadlock results. Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen" processes. For more information, see [Why are `Thread.stop`, `Thread.suspend` and `Thread.resume` Deprecated?](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/17/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Even with cooperating threads (where one thread voluntarily blocks itself until something happens) I am not aware of an existing concurrency class / API that provides what you are asking for; i.e. controlling task sequences based on thread names.

Maybe you can (and should) do what you want to achieve without relying on thread names.  For example:

- You could have a multiple executors each with its own queue, and a single worker thread.  One for the "A" tasks, one for the "B" tasks, and so on.
- You could implement this with `CompletionService` and `CompletionStage`.  Make "A2" a `CompletionStage` that consumes "A1", and so on.